# Custom shortcode in widget forced to top of widget

Tags: widgets, shortcode, widget-text

A custom shortcode i made is being forced to the top of the widget outside of the widget container. Any ideas why? This is my code...

```
function nktmediaplayer_func($atts) {
 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'id' => rand(1, 900),
    'language' => 'en',
    'playlist' => 'no',
    'media' => '3381',
    'height' => '480',
    'width' => '640',
    'style' => 'single'
    ), $atts));
    ?>

    <div id="player_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="video_player"><a href="http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/">Get the Flash Player</a> to see this player.</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kadampa.org/embed/apps/jwplayer.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jwplayer("player_<?php echo $id; ?>").setup({
            flashplayer: "http://kadampa.org/embed/apps/player.swf",
            playlistfile: "http://kadampa.org/<?php echo $language; ?>/api/video/<?php if ( 'playlist' == 'yes' ) echo 'playlist/'; ?><?php echo $media; ?>/desc",
            height: "<?php echo $height; ?>",
            width: "<?php echo $width; ?>",
            config: "http://kadampa.org/embed/config/<?php echo $style; ?>.xml"
        });
    </script>

    <?php    
}
add_shortcode('nkt_mediaplayer', 'nktmediaplayer_func', 10);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For shortcodes you have to *return* the output for it to be written out where the shortcode appears.

Either turn your HTML into a PHP string rather than breaking out of the PHP tags or you can use PHPs output buffering methods like so:

```
ob_start();

?>

    <div id="player_<?php echo $id; ?>" class="video_player"><a href="http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/">Get the Flash Player</a> to see this player.</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://kadampa.org/embed/apps/jwplayer.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jwplayer("player_<?php echo $id; ?>").setup({
            flashplayer: "http://kadampa.org/embed/apps/player.swf",
            playlistfile: "http://kadampa.org/<?php echo $language; ?>/api/video/<?php if ( 'playlist' == 'yes' ) echo 'playlist/'; ?><?php echo $media; ?>/desc",
            height: "<?php echo $height; ?>",
            width: "<?php echo $width; ?>",
            config: "http://kadampa.org/embed/config/<?php echo $style; ?>.xml"
        });
    </script>

<?php

$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return $output;
```

Comment: instead of the last 3 lines you could just use `return ob_get_clean()` :)

Comment: Cool. Didn't know `ob_end_clean()` returns the output aswell, thanks for the tip